CRON bash script certbot renew hangs
I have this script in /home/user/renew.sh
( cd /home/user/website/ && docker compose run --rm certbot renew --dry-run && docker compose kill -s SIGHUP webserver )

sudo crontab -e
*/5 * * * * /home/user/website/renew.sh >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1

result is it hangs at
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/website.conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

but if I execute the script sh renew.sh from my user manually then everything works fine
docker compose:
  certbot:
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    image: certbot/certbot
    container_name: certbot
    volumes:
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - data:/var/www/html
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
    command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email admin@wwebsite.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email --force-renewal -d web -d www.web

I don't understand why

I want to answer with comment, but.. my reputation is not enough to write a comment
So manually running script sh renew.sh works fine and sudo crontab -e is not working?
If you use sudo crontab -e -> you are running with root user
Then if you run just sh renew.sh -> you are running scripts with logined user
Can you tell me more about which user you are running scripts?
Also, try sh /home/user/website/renew.sh after change user to root (sudo su) , then check it is still working with root user

Thank you; it got me thinking.. I think the solution might be that I need to do crontab -e instead of sudo crontab -e but now my crontab is not executing at all so when I have solved this new issue will try that
